# What is the impact of a function on execution speed?

Tags: python-3.x, performance

Fairly new to python and working on an application where speed is critical - essentially in  a race to book reservations online as close to 7AM as possible. Was trying to understand the impact on execution speed that a function call has, so i developed a very simple test: count to 1,000,000 and time start and end using both in line and a called function. However, the result i get says that the function takes about 56% of the time that the inline code takes. I must be really be missing something. Can anyone explain this please.

Code:

```
import time
def timeit():
    temp = 0
    while temp < 10000000:
        temp += 1
    return
time1 = time.time()
temp = 0
while temp < 10000000:
    temp += 1
time2 = time.time()
timeit()
time3 = time.time()
temp = 0
while temp < 10000000:
    temp += 1
time4 = time.time()
timeit()
time5 = time.time()
print("direct took       " + "{:.16f}".format(time2 - time1)     + " seconds")
print("indirect took     " + "{:.16f}".format(time3 - time2)     + " seconds")
print("2nd direct took   " + "{:.16f}".format(time4 - time3)     + " seconds")
print("2nd indirect took " + "{:.16f}".format(time5 - time4)     + " seconds")
```

results:

direct took       1.6094279289245605 seconds

indirect took     0.9220039844512939 seconds

2nd direct took   1.5781939029693604 seconds

2nd indirect took 0.9375154972076416 seconds

I apologize for missing something silly that i must have done?

Comment: The `time.time()` function doesn't do what you're expecting. Try using `time.perf_counter()` instead.

Comment: thanks for the advice. However, same result with the new function - inline processing much slower than call to function.

Comment: Couple of thoughts: 1. `timeit` is actually a module, and it has a function `timeit`. You might try using that instead (beware of name clashes, though). 2. Sometimes programming languages have built-in optimizations, such that what we think of as optimized code works against the built-in optimizations. This leads to "premature optimization". As a colleague of mine has wisely said, "Make it work. Then make it work well. Then make it work fast *if you need to*." Sometimes simply making it work at all is enough.